# Ubuntu 14.04 Stuck after login

Tags: 14.04, login

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 last night on my Lenovo X200, Dual Core 2.4GHz 3GB RAM and 250GB HDD. Everything was working fine, and this morning when I powered it up to double check everything, it was all good.

I came into work and all booted up fine.

However, when I tried to login (password protected user); only user on the computer - It logged in fine but was stuck straight away, with the blank screen (the background of the login screen) and just my cursor. Nothing else.

I left it for a few minutes thinking it was just being a little slow, but to no avail nothing happened. I have tried a reboot and nothing happened.

Comment: Providing more information will be helpful. Like the screen color you see and what did you last dp to the system during the previous boot. Your Graphics card. What graphics software did you install on your system. Using Xorg?
I believe I have experienced this before. What I did, if I didn't forget is to boot on Ubuntu safe mode and reconfigure some graphics settings or installed something.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to fix this myself. What I have done is to reinstall the ubuntu desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Then I rebooted the machine using `sudo shutdown -r now`. This worked perfectly.