# Cannot login - screen just refreshes on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, login-screen

When I type the password to log in nothing happens, the only thing that happens is something similar to a refresh (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

When I type in a wrong password it says that it's wrong, while when I type in the correct one nothing happens at all.

Comment: Is this a new installation?  Or did it work before?

Comment: no it was working before

Comment: Just to be sure, you've checked Caps lock?

Comment: yup 
by the way i'am using just the numbers in the password

Comment: Can you ssh in from another computer or phone?

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity for a solution is the following.

when you arrive at the log in screen rather than 'loggin in' drop to a terminal. Normally you can do this with the  key combo (ie press the control key and any of the F keys).

You should get a login prompt.
Login in with your username and password.
you should now be able to start an X session with the

```
startx
```

command. If the login fails you can check the last few lines of the log file

```
tail -10 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

and post them here, in fact you probably want a copy if it works for comparison...keep reading.

Also whilst you are here maybe run a quick update, just to be sure

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f
```

The final one will fix any broken packages, just in case you have other problems on your system

If however everything works out fine, then there is something else going on on your login from the window manager.

So you'll need to log off, and then get back to the log in manager screen using the < ctrl F* > key combo (it normaly resides on F8, but may be different on your machine.

Don't log off your terminal log on just for the moment, you are going to need it.
re log in from the graphical screen and wait for the login to fail.

Now hop back to your still open terminal and re-issue that tail command to look at the Xorg log info. I should tell you where things are failing.

If you need more lines increase the value you send to the tail command to get extra lines.

If you still have problems you will need to find a way to post the output of the tail command to your qestion... something such as.

```
tail -10 /var/log/Xorg.0.log > ~/desktopFromCLIWorks.txt
```

and

```
tail -10 /var/log/Xorg.0.log > ~/desktopFailsFromLoginScrn.txt
```

Finaly have you tried other desktops ? if you have them.

Also I just found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482733/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-after-login?rq=1) here on Ask Ubuntu. where the OP used

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Clearly change ubuntu-desktop for the desktop that you are using. Again you'll need to run this from the CLI that you opened.

David

Comment: however cant i repair it or restore it ?

Comment: look bro i found a txt file in ubuntu disk which says ; A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x997e486d, pid=27764,

Comment: The reinstall switch is essentially restoring the desktop package. The rest should repair any other 'problems'. What it the name of the file where you got the Java runtime environment error? I dont expect it has anything to do with you other problems, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened to a friend of mine a couple years ago. It turned out to be an account management problem. His user had no home directory associated.

Try accessing another *tty* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
Log in as root and try:

```
# finger yourusername
```

You should see something like this:

```
Login: yourusername                     Name: Your User Name
Directory: /home/yourusername           Shell: /bin/bash
On since Tue Mar 10 09:08 (BRT) on :0 from :0 (messages off)
On since Tue Mar 10 09:25 (BRT) on pts/0 from :0
No mail.
No Plan.
```

If *Directory* is empty, add a new one:

```
# mkdir /home/yourusername
# chown -R yourusername:yourusername /home/yourusername
# usermod -d /home/yourusername yourusername
```

If it does exist, it could still be a permission problem. Ensure you have the ownership:

```
# chown -R yourusername:yourusername /home/yourusername
# chmod -R 755 /home/yourusername
```

Comment: how do i get my user name bcause i'm wrrting it with a greek letters .. ifont have this letters on keyboard

Comment: bro ; i found a txt file in home folder which says : A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x997e486d, pid=27764,